# Вызванный ключ не обращён к одноименной переменной

Tags: python

Скорее всего я бездарно сформулировал вопрос, но вот проблема:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
dict = {'a':a,'b':b}
b1 = max(dict, key=dict.get)
a1 = min(dict, key=dict.get)
print(b1,a1)
result = list(filter(lambda elem: elem in b1, a1))                                                        
print(result)
```

Задача в том, чтобы вернуть список, который состоит из элементов, общих для этих двух списков.

Да, можно было на глаз определить более длинный список и сразу вписать вместо b1 и a1 b и a:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
result = list(filter(lambda elem: elem in b, a))
```

Но что делать, когда список из тысяч значений? Как вернуть ключ из алфавита с большей длиной?

Comment: Я так и не понял, то есть если нам даны списки `а=[1,2]` и `b=[1]` то мы должны вернуть `res=[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не совсем понятно, вам нужны общие для двух списков элементы?

**вариант 1:**

```
res = list(set(a) & set(b))
```

**вариант 2:**

```
res = [v for v in a if v in b]
```

но тут будет две `1`, потому что они присутствуют в `a`

**вариант 3:**

```
res = [v for i, v in enumerate(a) if v in b and v not in a[:i]]
```

исправляет особенность варианта 2 и выдает такой же результат как вариант 1

**вариант 4 (если списки отсортированы):**

```
i = 0
j = 0

res = []

while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
    v1 = a[i]
    v2 = b[j]
    if v1 == v2:
        res.append(v1)
        i += 1
        j += 1
    elif v1 < v2:
        i += 1
    else:
        j += 1
```

**вариант 5:**

```
i = 0
j = 0

res = []

while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
    v1 = a[i]
    v2 = b[j]
    if v1 == v2:
        res.append(v1)
        while i < len(a) and j < len(b) and a[i] == b[j]:
            i += 1
            j += 1
    elif v1 < v2:
        while a[i] == v1 and i < len(a):
            i += 1
    else:
        while b[j] == v2 and j < len(b):
            j += 1
```

в отличии от варианта 4 не допускает дубликатов

Comment: насчёт второго варианта, подскажите почему нельзя написать [v for v in b if v in а] (поменял местами а и б)

Comment: а какая разница? можно , но 2 вариант в некоторых случаях будет выдавать дублирующие значения

Comment: Так в этом и смысл, должен выдавать вместе с дубликатами, когда мы ищем [v for v in b if v in а]  мы теряем одну из единиц('1')